# Finite etale coverings of a torus

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Suppose that $k[t, t^{-1}] \to A$ is a finite, etale morphism such that the corresponding map on spectra is surjective. How to prove that $A$ is isomorphic to $k[t, t^{-1}]$? Ideally, I would like to use as little as possible. For example, I'm wondering if one could avoid the (local) structure theorem.

Also, I would greatly appreciate any references with computing examples of such type.

Comment: This is false without more assumptions: for instance, $\Bbb R[t,t^{-1}]\to\Bbb C[t,t^{-1}]$.

Comment: @KReiser Yep, I forgot to mention that k is algebraically closed.

Comment: Isn't the diagonal $k [t, t^{-1}] \to k [t, t^{-1}] \times k [t, t^{-1}]$ also finite étale? You probably want a connectedness hypothesis too.